# PWA Angular app name stuck on old name after deployed - how to force an update?

Tags: angular

I've updated the

```
 "name": "new name",
 "short_name": "new"
```

in the manifest.json file but for some reason it is stuck on the old name and won't update when I add to my home screen on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was to have a little patience